# Another UISplitViewController + UITabBarController issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am adding multiple `UISplitViewControllers` to a single `UITabBarController`. The tabs appear, and each master/child view controller is loaded and displayed properly when the tab is clicked, **BUT** somehow user interaction only works on the last tab added.

If I add 1 tab, it works fine, but if I add 2 tabs, the 2nd one works and the 1st tab won't respond to user interaction (nothing happens when clicking user interface elements - they don't even highlight to show the click). If I add 3, the first 2 are break and the 3rd works.

How can I fix this? Here's the code (note: this method is called from a splashpage view controller at the end of a startup routine):

```
- (void)startIPad 
{
    UINavigationController *localNavigationController;
    UISplitViewController *localSplitViewController;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //setup the first tab
    Master1ViewController *viewMaster1 = [[Master1ViewController alloc] init];
    Detail1ViewController *viewDetail1 = [[Detail1ViewController alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewDetail1];
    localSplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    [localSplitViewController setDelegate:viewDetail1];
    localSplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewMaster1, localNavigationController, nil];
    [localControllersArray addObject:localSplitViewController];
    [viewMaster1 release];
    [viewDetail1 release];
    [localNavigationController release];
    [localSplitViewController release];

    //setup the second tab
    Master2ViewController *viewMaster2 = [[Master2ViewController alloc] init];
    Detail2ViewController *viewDetail2 = [[Detail2ViewController alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewDetail2];
    localSplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    [localSplitViewController setDelegate:viewDetail2];
    localSplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewMaster2, localNavigationController, nil];
    [localControllersArray addObject:localSplitViewController];
    [viewMaster2 release];
    [viewDetail2 release];
    [localNavigationController release];
    [localSplitViewController release];

    //setup the third tab
    ...

    //setup the fourth tab
    ...

    //set the UISplitViewControllers onto the tab bar
    tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
    [localControllersArray release];

    //switch to the new root view controller
    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    [tabBarController release];
}
```

Comment: According to [Split View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH7-SW1) in the "View Controller Catalog for iOS", a *split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create*. As I understand this, using a split view controller as one tab of a tab bar controller is not supported.

Comment: There are plenty of published apps out there configured like this (e.g. Flixster, etc). Also many posts on SO on how to add UISplitViewController to UITabBarController.

Comment: is there a reason you are not using ARC?

Comment: Not using ARC because it's an older project that I am adding an iPad presentation layer to (the iPhone presentation layer works fine). But can't see how this is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a dummy app with your code and its working fine in my app. Just i have initialize the appDelegate like this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    //self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self startIPad];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}



- (void)startIPad
{
    UINavigationController *localNavigationController;
    UISplitViewController *localSplitViewController;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //setup the first tab
    Master1ViewController *viewMaster1 = [[Master1ViewController alloc] init];
    Detail1ViewController *viewDetail1 = [[Detail1ViewController alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewDetail1];
    localSplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    [localSplitViewController setDelegate:viewDetail1];
    localSplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewMaster1, localNavigationController, nil];
    [localControllersArray addObject:localSplitViewController];
    [viewMaster1 release];
    [viewDetail1 release];
    [localNavigationController release];
    [localSplitViewController release];

    //setup the second tab
    Master2ViewController *viewMaster2 = [[Master2ViewController alloc] init];
    Detail2ViewController *viewDetail2 = [[Detail2ViewController alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewDetail2];
    localSplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    [localSplitViewController setDelegate:viewDetail2];
    localSplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewMaster2, localNavigationController, nil];
    [localControllersArray addObject:localSplitViewController];
    [viewMaster2 release];
    [viewDetail2 release];
    [localNavigationController release];
    [localSplitViewController release];

    //setup the third tab
   // ...

    //setup the fourth tab
    //...

    //set the UISplitViewControllers onto the tab bar
    tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
    [localControllersArray release];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //switch to the new root view controller
    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    [tabBarController release];
}
```

Comment: You're right. When I create blank UIViewControllers for the master and detail views the code works fine. There must be something going inside my UIViewControllers that is causing this strange behavior. The code that creates the layout is fine as you proved. I'll give you the points for noting that in fact the code above works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try release All (controllers,navigation,tabbarcontroller) after set window.rootviewcontroller.